# CreateView and UpdateView based class are not working in Django Project

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have Django in Which there is app called **Listing** and it's model as follows but **CreateView** and **UpdateView** are not woking for model. 
I am also using **mixins** but I have implemented **Custom User** , so is that cuases a problem?

1. getting error

```
in get_form return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
TypeError: 'ListingForm' object is not callable
```

2. Any other user is updating listing of others, **UserPassesTestMixin** not working

```
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
class Listing(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...other fields
```

**CreateView**

```
class ListingCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Listing
    form_class = ListingForm()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**UpdateView**

```
class ListingUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Listing
    form_class = ListingForm()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        listing = self.get_object()
        #print(self.request.user, listing.owner)
        if(self.request.user == listing.owner):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Listing


class ListingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ['price', 'sqft', 'acre', 'title', 'description', 'address', 'city', 'state',
                  'country', 'zipcode', 'photo_main', 'photo_1', 'photo_2', 'photo_3', 'photo_4', 'photo_5']
```

**Tysm for solving in advance!**

Comment: What do you mean with *not working*? What errors do you get, what is not updated?

Comment: Your `form_valid` in th ecreate view does not have the correct arguments.

Comment: I dont get any errors When I click on Sav Button while creating new listing it dosen't get added to my model Listing
Second problem is let's say I'm staff and there is Listing uploaded by admin but Still I can edit it. In short UserPassessTestMixin is returning true everytime I guess!

Comment: @schwobaseggl Then can you correct it?

Comment: @schwobaseggl  I edited it to valid_form(self, form) still not working

Answer (score 1):

You are missing  **[form_class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/)** in your update and create view. You need to be add your forms name.

CreateView

```
class ListingCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Listing
    form_class = your form name
    fields = blah blah blah
    

    def form_valid(self, form):
       form.instance.owner = self.request.user
       return super().form_valid(form)
```

UpdateView

```
class ListingUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Listing
    form_class = your form name

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        listing = self.get_object()
        #print(self.request.user, listing.owner)
        if(self.request.user == listing.owner):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: I got an error like improperly configured, which means that either id, owner or list_date is giving error becuase all other fields are in form. In models.py ```
list_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Noob_Coder you are doing mistake in your def form_valid or def test_func.